# Get name of default paper bin?

Tags: delphi, winapi, printing

I got a list of paper bins, using the WinAPI functionality DM_BINNAMES, and I also got a list of valid source indexes using DM_BINS .

But I would like to find out what the name of the default paper source is. How can I do this?

My current code looks like this, but it doesn't work at all. dmDefaultSource has value 258, which is greater than the array bin.

```
FPaperSourceIndex = -1; // default

function GetDefaultPaperbinName: string;
var
  pDevMode: PDeviceMode;
  bin: array[0..255,0..23] of char;
  i: DWORD;
  Res: DWORD;
  found: Boolean;
begin
  GetPrinter(ADevice,ADriver,APort,hDMode);
  pDevMode := nil;
  Res := DeviceCapabilities(ADevice,APort,DC_BINNAMES,PCHAR (@(bin[0][0])),pDevMode);

  if (FPaperSourceIndex <= integer(Res)) then
  begin
    if (hDMode <> 0) then
    begin
      pDevMode := GlobalLock(hDMode);
      if (pDevMode <> nil) then
      begin
        pDevMode^.dmFields := (DM_DEFAULTSOURCE or DM_PAPERSIZE);
        i :=  pDevMode^.dmDefaultSource;  // = 258
        result := bin[i]; // range Exception here
      end;
      GlobalUnlock(hDMode);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: your array is too small. User defined bins begin from 256 (==DMBIN_USER)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx) (emphasis mine)

> **dmDefaultSource**
>
> Specifies the paper source. To retrieve a list of the
>   available paper sources for a printer, use the DeviceCapabilities
>   function with the DC_BINS flag.
>
> This member can be one of the following values, **or it can be a
>   device-specific value greater than or equal to DMBIN_USER**.

DMBIN_USER is defined as 256 which explains why you get 258 in your example.

The solution is simple, widen the array to take in account device specific bins.

```
bin: array[0..511,0..23] of char;
```